# How to write a zsh alias that calls a subshell?

Tags: bash, alias, zsh

I am trying to create a `zsh` alias which would do the equivalent of:

```
cat `which some_command`
```

In bash that is not achievable with an alias so I had a function in my `~/.bashrc` with the following content:

```
function catw {
    cat `/usr/bin/which "${1}"`  
}
```

I moved the function to `~/.zhrc` without changes and it works, but while in `bash` it executes immediately with `zsh` I am getting a several seconds delay before the `cat` command actually runs.

Is there a way to have this as a more efficient `zsh` alias? If not then why does the function takes longer to execute? Can I change anything in the function to make it work as fast as in `bash`?

Comment: I tried your function in my zsh and `catw ldd` was pretty much instantaneous. Do you get the same lag when you repeat the command multiple times?

Comment: @thatotherguy: I have identified the issue: I had `cat` aliased to `ccat` (the colorizing cat from https://github.com/jingweno/ccat). The bash function apparently does not use the alias inside functions, while `zsh` probably tried to resolve the alias which caused the delay. Replacing `cat` with `/bin/cat` made the operation instant in `zsh`.

Comment: It's barely worth the effort in `zsh`: `cat =some_command`.

Comment: @chepner: can you please explain what you mean? and, if possible, maybe provide some links to examples?

Comment: `=some_command` is special syntax `zsh` provides which does the same thing as `which`. You can see by running `echo =some_command`.